# Comparing and finding the missing result

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a program that reads my Excel sheet and downloads an attachment from a website. It is then saved to a specific folder with a specific name that I have name in the Excel sheet. For example,

```
Column A - Column B
G135 - image01
G135 - image 02
G241 - document01
G748 - document01
```

Column A refers to folder name where the program will create a new folder with the name stated above.
Column B refers to the name of the file being saved by the program into the specific folder.

My program isn’t perfect and when I count the number of files in all of the folders through right click > properties, there is one file missing.

How can I compare my Excel sheet to my folders of files to find the missing file?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to install a module that deals with Excel or use COMObjects, save a copy of your spreadsheet as a CSV, we'll call it mydata.csv.  I am going to call the directory where all all these other directories are c:\basedir. I'm also going to assume each column has a header row (you can add one if it doesn't just for the CSV) and that column A is Folder and column B is FileName.  This should give you a basic idea of when a file isn't in the right place.

```
$MyData = Import-Csv -Path mydata.csv

Foreach ($File in $MyData) {
  $Location = Split-Path (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\basedir -Include $File.FileName -Recurse).DirectoryName -Leaf
  if ($File.Folder -ne $Location) {
    Write-Host "$($File.FileName) is in the wrong folder!"
    Write-Host "It should be in $($File.Folder) but it was found in $Location"
    Write-Host "----------------------------------------" # Just a visual separator
  }
  elseif ($null -eq $Location)  {
    Write-Host "$($File.FileName) was not found!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, if I’m not wrong, by looking at your code, does your code checks where is the missing file? Because I think my program didn’t download one of the files therefore there is a missing file. I would like to know which file did not get downloaded

Comment: sorry, I may have misunderstood your question, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Am I suppose to replace C:\basedir to my folders which contain the folders of the douments

Comment: @KimberKer yes, I am assuming the are all in one folder like this: `C:\basedir\G135, C:\basedir\G241, C:\basedir\G748`

Comment: The result they gave me was
 is in the wrong folder!
It should be in  but it was found in “full list of folder name”

Comment: Am I suppose to declare $File = something

Comment: $File iterates through $MyData, which is the data from your spreadsheet

Comment: There is 4100 files in my main folder but it’s suppose to have 4098 files only. After running the script above, it gives me this results. 

-blank- is in the wrong folder!
It should be in -blank- but it was found in *list of all of my folders in my main folder*

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample CSV data that simulates the contents of the Excel sheet.
$csvData = @'
ColumnA,ColumnB
G135,image01
G135,image02
G241,document01
G748,document01
'@

# Set the dir. in which to look for the files.
$refDir = '.'

# Process each CSV row.
# With a real CSV file as input, you'd use something like
#    Import-Csv c:\user\excel.csv
# instead of 
#    $csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv
$csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    # Construct the path to look for...
    $path = '{0}\{1}' -f $_.ColumnA, $_.ColumnB
    # ... and test its existence:
    if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $refDir\$path)) {
      # Output the missing path.
      [pscustomobject] @{ Missing = $path }
    }
  }
```

The above outputs one or more custom objects with the missing paths; e.g.:

```
Missing
-------
G241\document01
```

Comment: Hello, I’m sorry I’m confused. Do I put this as $csv = @‘c:\user\excel.csv’ @

Comment: @KimberKer: Instead of `$csvData | ConvertFrom-Csv`, use `Import-Csv c:\user\excel.csv` - please see my update.

Comment: I’m getting an error using Import-Csv, “Cannot bind parameter ‘Delimiter’. Cannot concert value “folder\excel.csv” to type “System.Char”. Error: “String must be exactly one character long.”

Comment: @KimberKer: That implies that you accidentally passed _2_ arguments, the 2nd of which is `folder\excel.csv`, which was interpreted as a value for the `-Delimiter` parameter, not the `-Path` / `-LiteralPath` parmeter - pass just 1 argument - unless you need additional parameters, in which case it is best to use their names; e.g., `Import-Csv -LiteralPath folder\excel.csv -Delimiter ','`

Comment: I’m getting “You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.” This is my code, Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\Users\Desktop\New Folder\excel.csv -Delimiter ‘,’ | foreach-object ...

Comment: @KimberKer: Since your path contains spaces, you must _quote_ it: `Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\Desktop\New Folder\excel.csv'` - no need for `-Delimiter ','`, because `,` is the default.

Comment: The output of missing files will be displayed in power shell after I enter the code?

Comment: @KimberKer: The output will be 1 custom object for each missing file, containing a single property, named `.Missing` whose value is the relative path of the missing file (e.g., `G241\document01`). The answer shows an example of what that looks like in the console. Of course, you can choose to output just the path strings; I just chose custom objects to make it more obvious what the output represents.

Comment: I’m not able to find the results

Comment: @KimberKer: If the code works as intended, that implies that all expected files are present.

Comment: Weird because my excel file shows that there’s 1000 record download but when I select all folders and right click > properties, it only shows 999 file

Comment: @KimberKer: One possible explanation is that there may be duplicates among the CSV rows. What does `Get-Content 'C:\Users\Desktop\New Folder\excel.csv' | Select-Object -Unique | Measure-Object` return?

Comment: My excel has 5513 lines with 5512 documents to download.
Below is the result.

Count:5462
Average:
Sum:
Maximum:
Minimum:
Property:

Comment: @KimberKer: That means that your CSV file has `5462` data rows, not `5512`.

Comment: @KimberKer: Allow me to give you some general advice: It sounds like you need help with the fundamentals of PowerShell (such as knowing that a literal argument with spaces must be quoted), which this site cannot provide. While your questions are clear in principle, they lack details, and people trying to help you get embroiled in lengthy exchanges about incidental problems that could be avoided with a better grasp of the fundamentals. I'm not trying to discourage you from asking questions, but please provide them in the form of an [mcve], and  perhaps turn to colleagues for basics.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you compare filenames ( and not full paths ). You should compare something like this :

```
$MyFolderFiles = (Get-ChildItem -path "c:").Name
$MyExcelList = Some code here to generate the file names list

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $MyFolderFiles -DifferenceObject $MyExcelList
```

Of course you'll need to tweak this for your actiual situation

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem -path "c:").Name` returns the names of files located _directly_ in the target directory, whereas the spreadsheet data references files _across subdirectories_.